# <console>:25: error: object databricks is not a member of package com

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I actually work on zeppelin with spark and scala. I want to import the library which contain : `import com.databricks.spark.xml`. 
   I tried but I have still the same mistake in zeppelin mistake : `<console>:25: error: object databricks is not a member of package com`.
   What I've done actually ? I create a note in Zeppelin with this code : `%dep
z.load("com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:jar:0.5.0")`. Even with that, the interpreter don't work. It's like it don't succeed to load the library.
   Have you an idea why it don't work ?
   Thanks for your help and have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very common and not intuitive to solve. I resolved an issue similar to this (I wanted to load the postgres jdbc connector in AWS EMR and I was using a linux terminal). Your issue can be resolved by checking if you can:

1. load the jar file manually to the environment that is hosting Zeppelin.
2. add the path of the jar file to your CLASSPATH environment variable. I don't know where you're hosting your files that manage your CLASSPATH env, but in EMR, my file, viewed from the Zeppelin root directory, was here:  `/usr/lib/zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh`
3. download the zeppelin interpreter with
   $ sudo ./bin/install-interpreter.sh --name "" --artifact
4. add the interpreter in Zeppelin wby going to the Zeppelin Interpreter GUI and add in the interpreter group.
5. Reboot Zeppelin with:

`$ sudo stop zeppelin
 $ sudo start zeppelin`

It's very likely that your configurations may vary slightly, but I hope this helps provide some structure and relevance.